# BindingList not firing PropertyChangedCallBack on DependecyProperty

Tags: mvvm, dependency-properties, bindinglist

I have the followin property in my VM.

```
private BindingList<DateTime> diasAgendados = new BindingList<DateTime>();
public BindingList<DateTime> DiasAgendados
        {
            get { return diasAgendados; }
            set { diasAgendados = value; RaisePropertyChanged("DiasAgendados"); }
        }
```

And the following method for adding a new item for the BindingList in the VM

```
private void AgregarFecha(DateTime agendar_fecha)
        {
            if (!DiasAgendados.Contains(agendar_fecha))
                DiasAgendados.Add(agendar_fecha);
        }
```

In my view i have the following dependency property

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty DiasAgendadosPropiedad = DependencyProperty.Register("DiasAgendados", typeof(BindingList<DateTime>),
            typeof(CalendarioView), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(DiasAgendadosProperty_Changed)));

        private static void DiasAgendadosProperty_Changed(DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var obj = (CalendarioView)sender;
            if (e.NewValue != null && obj.SelectedMes > 0 && obj.SelectedAnio > 0)
                obj.PintarCalendario((BindingList<DateTime>)e.NewValue);
        }

        public BindingList<DateTime> DiasAgendados
        {
            get { return (BindingList<DateTime>)GetValue(DiasAgendadosPropiedad); }
            set { SetValue(DiasAgendadosPropiedad, value); }
        }
```

Now if i manually set a new bindinglist already populated by default to the property in the VM the propertyChangedCallback will trigger.
But if try to add new items to the bindinglist in the VM it does not trigger.
I have already tried the following fix:

```
if (!DiasAgendados.Contains(agendar_fecha))
            {
                diasAgendados.Add(agendar_fecha);
                RaisePropertyChanged("DiasAgendados");
            }
```

Why isn't the propertyChangedCallback on the dependency property firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour, the property change should only be triggered when the property itself changes. If you want to get notification whenever the list items change then you need to change your DP type to the [`INotifyCollectionChanged Interface`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.inotifycollectionchanged(v=vs.110).aspx), change the lists themselves to something like [`ObservableCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) and subscribe-to/unsubscribe-from their `CollectionChanged` events in your DiasAgendadosProperty_Changed handler.